# Modelling time-varying financial exposures in `Neo4j`

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How would one model this kind of data in `Neo4j`?:

```
> HOLDINGS
   Portfolio                         Holding    Instrument       Date BALANCE.USD
1        ABC           Stock 1 Share Class A       Stock 1 2013-12-31    25360291
2        ABC           Stock 1 Share Class A       Stock 1 2014-01-31    25302011
3        ABC           Stock 1 Share Class B       Stock 1 2013-12-31    12264011
4        ABC           Stock 1 Share Class B       Stock 1 2014-01-31    12893201
5        DEF Fund 1 Share Class EUR Series 1        Fund 1 2013-12-31    21012222
6        DEF Fund 1 Share Class EUR Series 1        Fund 1 2014-01-31    21632101
7        DEF Fund 1 Share Class EUR Series 2        Fund 1 2013-12-31     8214325
8        DEF Fund 1 Share Class EUR Series 2        Fund 1 2014-01-31     8292630
9        DEF           Portfolio ABC Account Portfolio ABC 2013-12-31   155364592
10       DEF           Portfolio ABC Account Portfolio ABC 2014-01-31   156202162

> FACTORS
  Instrument                                         Factor ExposureStrength
1    Stock 1                              North America: US             1.00
2    Stock 1                                    Industrials             1.00
3     Fund 1                                 Liquidity: Low             0.05
4     Fund 1                                  North America             0.70
5     Fund 1                      Europe: Eurozone: Germany             0.20
6     Fund 1 Industrials : Capital Goods: Building Products             0.25
```

To give a little narrative, a portfolio invests into changing set of instruments (stocks, bonds, other portfolios ...) with **time-varying value**. The instruments in turn are sensitive to factors, which can be hierarchical, such as sectors [(e.g. GICS classification)](http://www.spindices.com/documents/index-policies/methodology-gics.pdf), regions/countries, size etc. Although it is not reflected in the `FACTORS` table above, `ExposureStrength` can vary with time too.

Portfolio exposure to each factor is then calculated as `Balance * ExposureStrength`. The aim is to later aggregate or slice&dice the exposures by different factor sets.

I am not yet an user of `Neo4j` but considering learning `Cypher` query language, so apologies for not posting reproducible example yet. Was curious how complex would `Cypher` snippets look like for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could model the time variance by creating one HoldingBalance node that is connected to a Portfolio and Instrument with a date reference, which have :NEXT relationships and are at the same time anchored in a time-tree for quick access of sub-sequences.

Something like this:

```
                (Portfolio)-->(Holding)<--(Instrument)
                                  |
                                  v
(HoldingBalance)<-[:NEXT]-(HoldingBalance)-->(day)-->(month)-->(year)
```

Same goes for factors

```
                     (Factor)-->(Exposure)<--(Instrument)
                                    |
                                    v
(ExposureStrength)<-[:NEXT]-(ExposureStrength)-->(day)-->(month)-->(year)
```

I started to model it as a graph-gist here, but it's not done yet:

http://gist.neo4j.org/?cace2732effa846d9fc2

Comment: Many thanks Michael for setting this up. I have put comments under the gist.